# [Cocoapods]:Resource Bundle not accessbile

Tags: ios, objective-c, resources, cocoapods

Before I was loading me resources with the podspec:

```
s.resources = ["MyFramework/Resources/**/*.{xib, png, jpeg, jpg}"]
```

now I tried to accomplish the same with the following:

```
s.resource_bundles = {'Resources' => ['MyFramework/Resources/**/*.{xib, png, jpeg, jpg}']}
```

They appear to be copied as I can find them under:

`Pods\Development Pods\MyFramework\Resources`

But when I try to load them:

```
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpeg"];
```

the `testImage` is always nil.

I also tried to find out if there was somehow a bundle accessible so I would need to load an image from a created bundle but:

```
NSArray *bundles = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:nil];
```

Revealed that no bundle was created through Cocoapods.

How exactly can I access those resources?

Comment: removing `use_frameworks!` in Podfile works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The resources is put in a bundle called 'Resources'.

```
s.resource_bundles = {'Resources' => ['MyFramework/Resources/**/*.{xib, png, jpeg, jpg}']}
```

you can access the bundle by the following code

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                 pathForResource:@"Resources"      
                                                          ofType:@"bundle"]];
```

The key in the `s.resource_bundles` is the bundle name.

Note:
I have some bundles listed by the following code. You may have other issues in your pod settings. 
    NSArray *bundles = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:nil];

Answer (score 0):

To load an image from a bundle use:

```
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Resources.bundle/testImage.jpeg"];
```